# What is correct way to use zipfile to archive each file?

Tags: python

Now I need to archive files separately under target path.

Here is the tree.

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\
|   file_1.py
|   file_2.py
|   file_3.py
|
\---Folder
        file_4.py
        file_5.py
```

Here is my code.

```
import os
import zipfile


def archive(file_path):
  for file_name in os.listdir(file_path):
    file = os.path.join(file_path, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(file):
      with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{file}.zip', 'w') as zip:
        zip.write(file)
      os.remove(file)

archive(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads')
```

I can actually archive `file_1.py`, `file_2.py`, and `file_3.py` separately. However, I opened `file_1.zip` and saw that not only the file is zipped but also contains the full path.

What is correct way to use zipfile to archive each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `write` functions 2nd parameter to specify the name of the file inside the archive. Just pass the file name to that. Also, use `os.walk()` to process all folders:

```
def archive(folder):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            zip_file = os.path.join(root, f'{file}.zip')
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'w') as zip:
                zip.write(full_path, file)
            # Delete original
            os.remove(full_path)
```